# Find value in Ruby hash

Tags: ruby

I have this Ruby hash this I use to get amount limits:

```
AMOUNT_LIMITS_FOR_TRX_TYPE = {
    zimpler: {
      eur: { min: 3_50,     max: 15_00_00 },
      sek: { min: 35_00,    max: 15_000_00 }
    },
    qiwi: {
      eur: { min: 5_00,     max: 350_00 },
      usd: { min: 5_00,     max: 500_00 },
      rub: { min: 500_00,   max: 15_000_00 },
      kzt: { min: 500_00,   max: 74_300_00 }
    },
    payu: {
      czk: { min: 1,        max: 1_000_000_00 },
      pln: { min: 1,        max: 1_000_000_00 }
    }
}.freeze

def amount_for(transaction_type, currency)
    p transaction_type
    p currency
    min_amount = AMOUNT_LIMITS_FOR_TRX_TYPE[transaction_type.to_sym][currency.to_sym][:min]
    max_amount = AMOUNT_LIMITS_FOR_TRX_TYPE[transaction_type.to_sym][currency.to_sym][:max]
    rand(min_amount..max_amount)
  end
```

I cal the method amount_for with params: `:zimpler` and `"SEK"` and I get error:

```
checks.rb:31:in `execute': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (RuntimeError)
/models/request_builders/request_builder.rb:246:in `amount_for'
```

Do you know where is my mistake and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing `"SEK"` as the `currency` argument and then try to access a hash value by:

```
currency.to_sym
```

But it returns `:SEK` instead of `:sek`. You probably need to fix it to:

```
currency.downcase.to_sym
```